# Ideal approach to create multi-player game server for Android (a game with very basic graphics)

Tags: android, sockets, rest

I'm working on an Android game based on Playing Cards ([Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_bridge), to be precise), which can be played by **four** players at time. And there'll be a server available via Web, to which devices will connect, and server will keep track of game progress.

My game is very basic when it comes to graphics that I can attain the UI without using any gaming engine.

While I'm supposed to build the game (the client) for Android, I wanted to develop server which can be **RE-USED** in future ports of the game, even if it is ported to other mobile platforms or even desktop.

So I thought of first possible candidate for server architecture was having **RESTful Web Service** so that I can leverage the server with any client as long as the client's programming end supports HTTP methods.

But later I realized that since there'll be persistent connection between devices and the server throughout the game session, would it be okay to have such a server, where connection will terminate after the request is responded (I'm not sure if it is true)?

Or shall I use `DatagramSocket` and `DatagramPacket` way of Java to build the server? (will that ensure re-usability of server?)

Any other suggestions or recommendations?

**Note:** I'm not new to Java or Network Programming in Java, **but I'm new** to both Android Development and creating RESTful services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your HTTP-based plan is appropriate for this situation, I don't think the question of persistence of connection is relevant for a slow turned based game such as bridge.

Edit:  as suggested by  tdreger almost all Android docs recommend that you plan for routine connection failure and reestablishment through a different channel, as such the html connection seems the most resilient solution.

I think your idea of making it client-side independent is correct and important - in this light the HTTP idea is clearly much better in that it will be **much** easier to code client-side applications in other languages (which you will probably want - Javascript for a web-client and objective-C for an iOS app).

I also think the Android development will be easier as Android and appache have strong support for these HTTP-like connections.

Comment: Okay so I should proceed the RESTful way? I haven't started digging much into creating RESTful services in Java, as I thought to first identify the situation before I start working and later realizing that RESTful is not a solution here.

Comment: Yes - I think the Restful way of doing things in appropriate as fdreger says below restful is more a strategy than a specific technology.

Answer (score 3):

While writing for Android, don't plan for a persistent connection. Connections break very often (and often for good reasons, like switching from GSM to wifi). HTTP is a great, popular and proven choice (you get some lower levels of the stack out of your way and can focus on processing the payload).

BTW: saying "RESTful web service" int this context is meaningless - what you need is a HTTP server that serves data and accepts commands, not a mental framework for structuring your game logic as a set of stateful resources.